# Form of object created from another object in c#

Tags: c#

I have a form containing a flowlayoutpanel, and a user control A is added to the panel. In the constructor of user control A, a pointer to the same flowlayoutpanel is passed, so that user control A creates another user control B in the same flowlayoutpanel. The problem is that user control B is first added, then A.

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Graphic1(this.flowLayoutPanel1));


    }
}
```

Graphic1.cs

```
public partial class Graphic1 : UserControl
{
    public Graphic1(FlowLayoutPanel flowPointer)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        flowPointer.Controls.Add(new Graphic2());
    }
}
```

Graphic2.cs is just a label

problem is that Graphic2.cs is added before Graphic1.cs in the panel

Comment: Why is it a problem that control B is added before control A?

Comment: Code would be helpful for a better solution to be given

Comment: This is very unclear and lacks code of what you have tried

Comment: What GUI toolkit are you using? WinForms? Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Also, maybe [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425867/reordering-of-controls-within-a-flow-layout-panel) is related/solves your problem.

Comment: Display, because i m displaying an xml file, and user cntrol B is the attributes of an element, an first need to display the inner text (user controlA), then the attibutes (user control B)

Comment: I ll post a sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three possible solutions:

- If the constructor of control A receives the flow layout panel, have control A add *itself* to the flow layout panel, then add its additional controls.
- Instead of adding the additional control in the constructor of control A, add a method such as `InitializeLayout` to control A. You can invoke that method *after* adding control A to the flow layout panel, and that method could then add any additional controls to the flow layout panel.
- Capture any changes to the `Parent` property of control A (not sure whether that is possible; that depends on the GUI toolkit you are using) and add the additional controls when the parent of control A has changed.