# Reorder customcontrol inside multiple flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, custom-controls, flowlayoutpanel

I am trying to make an app to generate a tierlist.
Each tier consists of a flowlayout and you basically move the controls around by drag-and-drop.
[image]
The problem is that even though I can move the elements with drag-and-drop, the element is always added to the end of the list, and not where you drop the pointer.
Is there any way to maintain order during drag-and-drop?

These are the methods that are in the flowlayout

```
private void flow_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}
private void flow_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    ((UserControl1)e.Data.GetData(typeof(UserControl1))).Parent = (Panel)sender;
}
```

While these are from the usercontrol:

```
private void UserControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.DoDragDrop(this, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can opt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207363/14171304) solution to reorder the dropped controls into a  `FlowLayoutPanel` control. The part that utilizes the [`Control.ControlCollection.GetChildIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.getchildindex?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.GetChildIndex)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) and [`Control.ControlCollection.SetChildIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex?view=netframework-4.8) methods.

Let's say you have a custom Control or UserControl named `DragDropControl`:

```cs
public class DragDropControl : Control
{
    public DragDropControl()
    {
        AllowDrop = true;
        BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, 
            ClientRectangle, Color.Black, 
            TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter |
            TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
    }       
}
```

<sup>**Note:** From what I see in the images, just use a simple `Label` control instead.</sup>

Let's create a custom `FlowLayoutPanel` and encapsulate all the required functionalities to not repeat that in your implementation for each `FLP`.

```cs
public class DragDropFlowLayoutPanel : FlowLayoutPanel
{
    public DragDropFlowLayoutPanel()
    {
        AllowDrop = true;            
    }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public override bool AllowDrop 
    { 
        get => base.AllowDrop; 
        set => base.AllowDrop = value; 
    }
```

The custom `FLP` implements the mouse, drag and drop events of its children as well.

```cs
    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlAdded(e);

        if (e.Control is DragDropControl)
        {
            e.Control.DragOver += OnControlDragOver;
            e.Control.DragDrop += OnControlDragDrop;
            e.Control.MouseDown += OnControlMouseDown;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlRemoved(e);

        e.Control.DragOver -= OnControlDragOver;
        e.Control.DragDrop -= OnControlDragDrop;
        e.Control.MouseDown -= OnControlMouseDown;
    }
```

Handle the child controls `MouseDown` event to do the drag:

```cs
    private void OnControlMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            var control = sender as DragDropControl;
            DoDragDrop(control, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
```

Handle the `DragEnter` and `DragOver` methods and events of the `FLP` and its children to set the drop effect.

```cs
    protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDragEnter(e);

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(DragDropControl)))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDragOver(e);

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(DragDropControl)))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void OnControlDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetData(typeof(DragDropControl)) is DragDropControl ddc)
        {
            var p = PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            if (GetChildAtPoint(p) == ddc)
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
    }
```

Finally, call from the `DragDrop` method override and event the `DropControl` method and pass the `DragEventArgs` param.

```cs
    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDragDrop(e);
        DropControl(e);
    }

    private void OnControlDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DropControl(e);
    }
```

The dropped control takes the index of the control under the mouse position if any otherwise it will be inserted at the end of the `Controls` collection.

```cs
    private void DropControl(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetData(typeof(DragDropControl)) is DragDropControl ddc)
        {
            var p = PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            var child = GetChildAtPoint(p);
            var index = child == null
                ? Controls.Count
                : Controls.GetChildIndex(child);

            ddc.Parent = this;
            Controls.SetChildIndex(ddc, index);
        }
    }
}
```

Put it all together.

```cs
public class DragDropFlowLayoutPanel : FlowLayoutPanel
{
    public DragDropFlowLayoutPanel()
    {
        AllowDrop = true;            
    }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public override bool AllowDrop 
    {
        get => base.AllowDrop; 
        set => base.AllowDrop = value; 
    }

    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlAdded(e);

        if (e.Control is DragDropControl)
        {
            e.Control.DragOver += OnControlDragOver;
            e.Control.DragDrop += OnControlDragDrop;
            e.Control.MouseDown += OnControlMouseDown;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlRemoved(e);

        e.Control.DragOver -= OnControlDragOver;
        e.Control.DragDrop -= OnControlDragDrop;
        e.Control.MouseDown -= OnControlMouseDown;
    }

    protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDragEnter(e);

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(DragDropControl)))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDragOver(e);

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(DragDropControl)))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDragDrop(e);
        DropControl(e);
    }

    private void OnControlDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetData(typeof(DragDropControl)) is DragDropControl ddc)
        {
            var p = PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            if (GetChildAtPoint(p) == ddc)
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
    }

    private void OnControlDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DropControl(e);
    }

    private void OnControlMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            var control = sender as DragDropControl;
            DoDragDrop(control, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }

    private void DropControl(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetData(typeof(DragDropControl)) is DragDropControl ddc)
        {
            var p = PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            var child = GetChildAtPoint(p);
            var index = child == null
                ? Controls.Count
                : Controls.GetChildIndex(child);

            ddc.Parent = this;
            Controls.SetChildIndex(ddc, index);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: SO75471363]

Comment: DragDropFlowLayoutPanel should be added as?
I tried with a normal class but it doesn't appear on the ToolBox.
Right now I have a bunch of FlowLayoutPanel

Comment: @PercivallAkihiko Copy & Paste the code in a new class. Paste it within your project's namespace and rebuild. You'll find it at the top of the ToolBox under your project's components group. Open the `Form.Designer.cs` file that hosts the FLPs and change the types of `FlowLayoutPanel` to `DragDropFlowLayoutPanel` and you are done.

Comment: Thanks it worked, basically I tried to rebuild but the class still didn't appear in the toolbox, I closed and reopen the project. @dr.null