# C# drag & drop panel (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, controls

I would like to create a C# draggable panel. What I want to do is to implement a drag and drop operation between two panels, so that one panel is the receiving panel for a few other panels which can be dragged onto it.

I've searched for tutorials and youtube videos but most show how to drag and drop files onto panels, not how to make a panel draggable. There is one NuGet package that adds draggables to winform controls but it's not a default windows drag and drop operation, it's just aesthetically changing the position of the control on the screen.

I've made this quick sketch in paint about what I want to do.
[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?546530-Drag-amp-Drop-in-Windows-Forms) out. Dragging files onto a form is one of the things it covers but it also covers dragging within the same form. You need to come back with a more specific issue than "how do I do drag and drop", so see what you can manage for yourself based on that and then let us know what specific issue you encounter, if any at all.

Comment: [Drag and drop panels within a FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77167210/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi this is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thank you!